# I want to bring youtube results in a frame, as in the website mp3skull.com. how do I start? I am using JSP - jQuery

Tags: jquery, mysql, jsp, youtube, frame

On search of a mp3 song ,I want the song from thе database and the youtube result for the same song .

Answer (score 0):

I like to stress that it is important to provide the code you're facing a problem with, and not a general issue that a Developer would need to provide multiple solutions for.

Anyway, straight out of the horses mouth, utilizing the Youtube API allows you to search for Videos on your website...

```
http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/getting_started.html#data_api
```

And quoted from the first paragraph....

> *The Data API allows a program to perform many of the operations available on the YouTube website. It is possible to search for videos, retrieve standard feeds, and see related content. A program can also authenticate as a user to upload videos, modify user playlists, and more.*

The second paragraph strongly supports my initial thoughts..

> *The Data API is **primarily for developers** who are used to programming in server-side languages. It is useful for sites or applications that wish to have a deeper integration with YouTube*

Good luck.